# ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:18.1.0 Show in Project Structure dialog Affected Modules: app

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio

I am trying to include the firebase authentication hence, I included a line of code from firebase authentication into my Android Studio App Gradel Dependency. Due to this, an error message occurs show "ERROR: Failed to resolve:com.google.firebase:firebase-core:18.1.0 Show in Project Structure dialog Affected Modules: app" when I started to sync the gradle.

To sort this from my side, I clicked on app link highlighted in the message which further shows a dialog box included all dependencies contains upgrade option, so I was upgraded all of them one by one.

But the problem is still standing, and the error message is still displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Correct version should be

```
implementation com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1
```

Check version [history](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android)

Check setup process for more information: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup